# Reverse Geocoding/MapKit on OSX?

Tags: cocoa, macos, google-maps, mapkit

the iPhone SDK provides with MapKit a simple solution for maps und reverse geocoding without any additional costs. Does anyone know if there is a similar Framework for Cocoa on OSX? I know that google maps is capable of that but as far as I know and understand I have to pay while using google maps in a commercial application?

Thanks for your answers

twickl

Comment: What specific reverse geocoding tasks are you trying to achieve?  there are free libraries for some things.

Comment: I get the coordinates of a user in my Application and now I want to get the Info where he is (Country, City, Street) and also show him on a map. With map kit and Core Location is that no problem but I have no idea what to use in OSX, espacially as I'm looking for a free Framework.

Thank you

twickl

Comment: Similar question [which answers the MapKit part of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689345/a-mapkit-for-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to pay as long as you don't use the quota.
The api documentation is here :
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

If you plan to use it reasonably, this will remain free (no api key is required anymore by google)