# A MapKit for Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, view, maps, mapkit

on the iPhone we have the Apple's amazing MapKit. There is something similar for Mac OS X?

If possible something more advanced than a simple WebView, because I need that it manage automatically at least:

- annotations
- the user interaction
- the zoom in/out
- an overlay view

(Even if the maps are not from Google is ok.)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477512/reverse-geocoding-mapkit-on-osx

Comment: You are probably right. However, this question is more specific. Furthermore, no one has yet answered the question that you reported. So, unfortunately, I guess the answer is no. Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update 2**

MapKit is available in OS X 10.9 Mavericks : [Map Kit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html).

**Update** - pulled from my comment below

The situation has changed and there now exists a third party MapKit for Mac OS X. Find it at http://github.com/Oomph/MacMapKit and a small writeup at http://rickfillion.tumblr.com/post/1134987954/pretroducing-mapkit-for-mac

---

**Orginal Answer**

There is no such API from Apple on Mac OS X. You should file a bug request at [bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

The best alternative is to use the Google Maps JavaScript API embedded in a WebKit view. Visit the [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) to understand the API.

I realize that you asked for more then a simple WebView, but perhaps you're unaware of some of the more advance functionality a WebKit view allows.

Webkit provides means for bridging between the JavaScript scripting environment in your WebKit view and the rest of your Cocoa application.

To call a Javascript function from Objective-C, use your WebKit view's WebScriptObject. "[Using Javascript From Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001214-BCIIEAFH)" from the "[WebKit Objective-C Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html)" is a great place to start learning.

If you need to call back into your Cocoa application from Javascript, "[Calling Objective-C Methods From JavaScript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215-BBCBFJCD)" in the "[WebKit DOM Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html)" provides examples and explanation.

These technologies used carefully together should provide the functionality you require.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful response!

Comment: The situation has changed and there now exists a third party MapKit for Mac OS X. Find it at https://github.com/Oomph/MacMapKit and a small writeup at http://rickfillion.tumblr.com/post/1134987954/pretroducing-mapkit-for-mac.

Comment: Ehi, great! Consider answer the original question. So I can give you my up-vote.

Comment: MacMapKit broke one day completely out of the blue. I think it was a minor update Lion that did it or it could have been Google's API change. Not sure.  I got a few bad ratings in the App Store, removed one of the more tricky features and resubmitted the app. Then when Mountain Lion came out, it broke again. I fixed it and resubmitted but Apple won't approve it because the bug still shows up on their system. I recommend against using this software until the author fixes it. It's been 5 months since they updated it as of this writing. Ouch.

Comment: MacMapKit is still just a WebView and not what I would call a native mapping solution for Mac OS X.  It is "simply" implementing what you suggested in your original answer.  It is also restricts you to Google maps.