# Is there any Mapping Toolkit for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-maps, mapping

I want to create a native Mac OS X mapping application. I am using Xcode for the development. My problem is I was unable to find any Mapping Library for MAC OS X. I don't want to use the WebKit and show google maps inside it.

Do anyone has any ideas..

Thanks,
Nitin Agarwal.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make do with WebKit and the Google Maps API, unfortunately. Mac OS X doesn't have MapKit unlike iOS and there's no sign of it in Lion either. Good luck!

**EDIT:**

There are of course many ways of [hiding the fact that you're using WebKit](http://www.josephcrawford.com/macdev-articles/google-maps-in-a-cocoa-application/) but if they violate Apple's or Google's TOS then submission to the App Store won't be possible.

Things like pins on Google Maps for iPhone are difficult to replicate but [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123) is available on both platforms if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

As being answered in [A MapKit for Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689345/a-mapkit-for-mac-os-x):

MapKit is available in OS X 10.9 Mavericks: [Map Kit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html)

Also there is a third party MapKit for Mac OS X. Find it at http://github.com/Oomph/MacMapKit and a small writeup at http://rickfillion.tumblr.com/post/1134987954/pretroducing-mapkit-for-mac